# How do I handle file uploads in a Nuxt server route?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify, primevue

Have a server route that I'm using to handle a file upload:

```
const files = await readMultipartFormData(event);
console.log("type: ", typeof files);
console.log("Files: ", files);
if (!files || files.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("No files attached");
}
```

/api/[id]/files/index.post.ts

After this I upload it to supabase. Route works correctly correctly on localhost. However, whenever i deploy to Netlify, an error is thrown because the files array is empty. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is? The front end component is a PrimeVue file upload component.